# Salesforce - Sales Cloud - Order Of Implementation

Tags: sales-cloud, sales

I've waltz myself through the Trailhead learnings and I have general understanding of the different objects and functionalities of Salesforce - Sales Cloud.

Coming from an SAP background  all the Salesforce functionalities are very well documented.

There is only 1 thing I can't find which is an order of functionality implementation.

In short, the questions is where should you start and where should you end?

Logically to me you would start with:

1. Company Settings
2. Objects, Custom Objects with related Fields to Support Processes
3. Flows
4. Validations
5. Security
6. Reports & Dashboards

But I'm a mere mortal here compared to some of the Salesforce gods on this Community, so looking forward to guidance from you.

Thank you.

Kind regards,
Vincent

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! This question has attracted some votes to close as opinion-based, and I myself am not really sure what the core of your question is. Outside of things that have strict dependencies (e.g. you need to have an SObject before you can define a validation rule or add a page layout), there's no general guide about "do thing X before thing Y" aside from the "clicks before code" mentality (i.e. see if a standard feature that you can configure from the UI like validation rules, approval processes, and record-triggered flows can do what you need before you try to write code).

Comment: @DerekF I think that there is no logical order on how to tackle a sales cloud implementation. For example I'm now doing the implementation and I've started with creating a new Sales app. Define the objects which are needed, created some custom objects. To me I was wonder if there is like a checklist which you could go through to tackle a project. Based on this checklist you could also guide your workshops with customers. This is an SAP guide as a reference: https://help.sap.com/doc/cc751d98800d414ca72fc4695a9bf3e7/2105/en-US/SF_EC_Master_Impl.pdf